# Will Return to Duty get someone out of the Brig?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

The other day, when playing Battlestar Galactica, we had all (bar the CAG) been brigged, and someone drew the crisis *Return to Duty* card.

> ## Turn 5 Crisis: Return to Duty
>
> CAG Chooses
>
> - Any character on Galactica with piloting in his skill set may immediately launch himself in a viper. Then: Basestars Launch Raiders
>
> **OR**
>
> - Basestars Attack Galactica
>     Raiders Activate

Can the CAG pick the top one and get the character out of the brig? We ruled no, as it made it too easy, but it does sort of make sense to me (and comes with its own downside).

Comment: There are similar issues that arise with automatic moves of character's abilities (either moves into vipers or into the sickbay). We have a house rule that just says "you can't cheat your way out of the brig" for such occasions.

Comment: Is it really 'cheating' your way out though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the rules are fairly explict about getting out of the Brig.

> Players may move out of “Sickbay” without difficulty, but not the “Brig.” They may only move out of the “Brig” by passing the skill check listed on the location.

Piloting Vipers

> A player who wants his character to pilot a viper simply moves his character to the “Hangar Deck” location and uses the action listed there.

Also from the [BSG Errata](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_1-1-3-new.pdf), although it doesn't mention your particular example, it is a similar move a character from the Brig to some other location.

> Q: If a character is in the “Brig,” and a card sends him to “Sickbay,” is he moved from the “Brig?”
>   A: No. This reflects a change from previous rulings.